# Call forEach from anonymous function and store the result to variable

Tags: javascript

I need to get an `array` as input and store the `result` to be used, without creating other functions because I have no access. So the code must be  what `result` can get.

```
let array = [[1,2,3,4,5,10],[1,2,3,4,5,20]];
let result = array
    .forEach(
        function(el){
            if(el[5] == 10)
            {
                return(el); //must store to variable, but this doesn't work
            }
        }
    )
```

I know I'm missing the point but can't figure it out. How can I make this work?

Comment: `.forEach()` ignores any returned values from its callback. Perhaps you want `.filter()` instead, or a combination of `.filter()` and `.map()`.

Comment: I see, this is not so clear on mozilla docs. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Since you need only some especific elements, you need a make a filter on the array

```
let array = [[1,2,3,4,5,10],[1,2,3,4,5,20]];
let result = array.filter((el) => el[5] == 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter()`.

```
let result = array.filter(el => el[5] === 10);
```